# Average number of moves to have a specific 3-bit pattern

Tags: probability, graph-theory, python, pattern-matching

I would like to know how to have the average number of moves to have a specific 3-bit pattern.
It is a random test where the chance of having 0 or 1 is the same: 0.5 (like having a coin toss).
We drag 0 or 1 several times in a row until we have the pattern we are looking for.
The purpose of my problem is to know which pattern has the lowest average number of moves.
So in 3-bit all the patterns are
001, 110,
100, 011,
101, 010,
111, 000.
I maked a program in python to know approximately the average number of moves of each patterns: (here 100)

```
def jump(p) :
    x=random.random()
    if x<=p :
        s=1
    else:
        s=0
    return s

summi = 0

for j in range(100):

    i = 0

    tab = []

    while True:
        nb = jump(0.5)
        print("Random number", nb)
        tab.append(nb)
        if i > 2 :
            if ( tab[i-2]== 1 ) and ( tab[i-1]== 0 ) and ( tab[i]== 0 ):
                break
        i += 1

    summi += i

print("Average : ", summi/100)
```

For example for 111: this is ~14 and for 100: this is ~8.
I tried to make probability trees. So I have infinite trees: for example for a pattern of "111" if I have "11" and I add a "0" it is not good and I continue in my tree (this looks more like a graph than a tree).
But I noticed that more simply I could go back to a previous state: if I add a "0" after an "11" then I go back to the root of my tree.
My calculation to have the average number for "111" is then Ex = 1/8*3 + 1/8*(3 + Ex) + 1/4*(2 + Ex) + 1/2*(1 + Ex).
 1/8*3 is the path for "111", 1/8*(3 + Ex) is the path to start again after "110", 1/4*(2 + Ex) is the path to start again after "10" and 1/2*(1 + Ex) after "0".
For "111" this is easy but for others such as "100" I don't start from the beginning of my tree. For example for the pattern "100", if I have "10" and I add a "1" I go back to the node where I added a "1" in the "10" : not at the root of the tree.
Here is a drawing of my trees with "P" and "F" (same as "0" and "1").
[trees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObxUe.png)

in high quality: https://ibb.co/T2WdYT1

Comment: You've already found a good approach. You might want to look at [Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain). What exactly is your question?

Comment: My general question would be: Knowing that a test is to draw a "0" or a "1", in every possibilities of a 3-bit wich pattern is the most recurrent ? For that reason we say that we stop the test as soon as we have found the pattern we are looking for and we count the number of times we have had a "0" or a "1". My objective is to calculate the average number of moves to get each pattern.
Alright I will look for this thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "the most recurrent"? In an infinite string, every $3$-bit pattern occurs every $2^3=8$ bits on average. You're looking at how long you expect to wait until you see it for the first time starting from scratch. I'm not sure what notion of "recurrence" you're relating that to.

Comment: Yes, sorry you are right, my problem is more like I expect to wait until you see it for the first time starting from scratch.

Comment: So, again, what exactly is your question? You've already worked out a way to do it. Do you want another way to do it?

Comment: I don't think my method is good for some cases (like 100) so I'm open to any other way to do it. So, my question is: Knowing a 3-bit pattern, we draw a "0" or "1" with a probability of 0.5 for each. The probability test stops when we get the pattern. The number of moves made during the event is counted. How to find the average number of moves to reach the pattern ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is generally applicable; you just need to introduce more variables if you have more than one state to fall back to.

For instance, for $100$: Let $E_1$ be the expected number of moves after you've seen a $1$; let $E_{10}$ be the expected number of moves after you've seen a $10$; and let $E$ be the expected number of moves otherwise. Then the expected number of moves when starting from scratch is $E$.

Similarly to how you proceeded, we can set up the following equations:

\begin{eqnarray*}
E&=&1+\frac12E+\frac12E_1\;,\\
E_1&=&1+\frac12E_1+\frac12E_{10}\;,\\
E_{10}&=&1+\frac12E_1\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Using the third equation to eliminate $E_{10}$ in the second yields

$$
E_1=1+\frac12E_1+\frac12+\frac14E_1
$$

and thus $E_1=6$. Substituting that into the first equation then yields $E=8$.

Comment: I'm trying to make "101" with your method but I end up with something difficult to solve. I have E = 1+1/2*E+ 1/2*E1, E1 = 1+1/2*E1 + 1/2*E10, E10 = 1 + 1/2*E. Am I on the right tracks ?

Comment: @SourouCerulean: Please learn to use MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference; it's a bit of a strain to read the formulas the way you write them

Comment: @SourouCerulean: Yes, you're on the right track there.